# How to analyze a HTTP response including the chunks

Tags: http, server, http-headers, client-server, httprequest

I am reading a HTTP response from a service where the `Content-Encoding` is set to gzip and `Transfer-Encoding` is set to `chunked`. On inspect of the response on the browser, I don't see the exact number of chunks that is sent in the response. Is there a tool or a code that lets me know the number of chunks in response and read each individually.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a little overkill, but you might use a network sniffer to see all packets.

Wireshark https://www.wireshark.org/ is a good one. See also my answer to another post:
[Mapping HTTP requests to HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163636/mapping-http-requests-to-http-responses/2164926#2164926)